# Success Callback for emit method in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Im trying to emit a custom message from my client. I need to perform some actions on its success and failure. Now, how can i attach the success callback to emit method?

For error callback , i used [Exposed events](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Exposed-events) doc and got it working

```
socket.on('error', () -> console.log("Error Occured"))
```

For success, i tried

```
socket.emit('my custom method', {content: json},() -> console.log("Emitted"))
```

This callback is never been triggered irrespective whether its a success or failure.

How can i get hold of success handler?

Comment: Please unaccept [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13550139/5583289) answer in favour of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22086758/5583289) one.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If you look at the docs, it shows you an example of passing a call back function -2nd last example: http://socket.io/docs/#Sending-and-getting-data-acknowledgements

Ex
server:

```
    socket.on('formData', 
              function(data, fn){
                      // data is your form data from the client side
                      // we are here so we got it successfully so call client callback
                      // incidentally(not needed in this case) send back data value true 
                      fn(true);
              }
             );
```

client:

```
      socket.emit('formData', 
                  data, 
                  function(confirmation){
                          // send data
                          // know we got it once the server calls this callback      
                          // note -in this ex we dont need to send back any data 
                          // - could just have called fn() at server side
                          console.log(confirmation);
                  }
                 );
```

Comment: Does this not work in reverse? I tried sending a callback function from the server and invoking it on the client and it doesn't seem like the callback even makes it to the client.

Comment: +1 Note also that this doesn't work on broadcasting https://github.com/cayasso/primus-rooms/issues/28

Comment: I would think the marked answer is a sloppy way to do it when you can pass callback function and trigger the callback with data on socket.on event.

Answer (score 18):

The reason why your second code is not doing anything is because exposed events in socketIO are just defined for `socket.on` methods. Therefore you need to add another emit in your server app.js to accomplish this

**Client** emits the custom message and sends JSON data to the socket via socket.emit, also he gets an update function that handles the success callback

```
socket.emit ('message', {hello: 'world'});
socket.on ('messageSuccess', function (data) {
 //do stuff here
});
```

**Server-side** Gets a call from the message emit from the client and emits the messageSuccess back to the client

```
socket.on ('message', function (data) {
 io.sockets.emit ('messageSuccess', data);
});
```

You could probably make a module out of this behavior so you can attach this for every message that you want to be handled that way.

Comment: I'm a little bit puzzled, which way is better, `emit` event from server or sent callback function from client. `socket.emit ('message', {hello: 'world'}, function() { //do stuff here });` Is there any difference between these two methods?

Comment: Shouldn't the callback function still work though?  Why does the callback not work 100%, I can get the callback working 50%.

Comment: This shouldn't be the "right" answer since socket.io support "acknowledgements functions" where you can pass function called on the "other side". Please see the other anser!

Comment: Though this may not be the "right" answer. But when using a non-standard (or, not complete) socket.io clients (as, python-socketio) with no acknowledgment support yet, this is the way you do it. Correct me if I am wrong.