# How can I wait for return of socketIO event?

Tags: javascript, callback, socket.io, synchronous

I must return to the validate function de OK of the debugReturn event but I don't know how because is asynchronous. I need a way to return true or false to the validate function. Sorry for my english :S

```
$('.num-pad').keyboard({
    layout: 'num',
    validate: function(keyboard, value, isClosing) {
        var data = $(keyboard['el']).attr('id').split('_');
        var var_index = data[data.length - 1];
        var var_name = data[0];
        for (var i = 1; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
            var_name += '_';
            var_name += data[i];
        }
        socket.emit('debugVar', {
            var_value: value,
            var_name: var_name ,
            var_index: var_index 
        });

        socket.on('debugReturn', function(msg) {
            if (msg == 1) {
                $('.ui-keyboard input').css('box-shadow', 'inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6)');
                return true;
            } else {
                $('.ui-keyboard input').css('box-shadow', 'inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(255,0,0,.6)');
                return false;
            }

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You don't use synchronous returns with async functions. You should use callback(true) or callback(false). The problem is that keyboard widget might not be able to accept async calls as validation function.

Comment: I know that the "return" are useless for asynchronous functions. I was thinking about how to use a callback to get out of trouble but I do not see how. I have been searching libraries allow delayed functions execution but I haven't found anything to convince me.

Comment: is this the plugin? https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard Because the author has "waiting for requests" in his todo list. perhaps you should create an issue there.

Comment: Yes, this is the plugin that I'm using. How can I see the todo list?

Comment: There isn't, but down the readme there's a small section. Are you familiar with github? Every project has an issue page in which you can leave feedback, or suggest features. But the nicest you can do is look at the unminified source code and try to enhance the plugin by youself, and then become a contributor to the code base. In this case, the feature you need implemented would need knowledge of callbacks and perhaps jQuery promises.

Comment: Take a look at this question too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549734/success-callback-for-emit-method-in-socket-io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem handling the keyboard from outside the validate function

```
$('.num-pad').keyboard({
  layout: 'num',
  validate: function(keyboard, value, isClosing) {
      var data = $(keyboard['el']).attr('id').split('_');
      var var_index = data[data.length - 1];
      var var_name = data[0];
      for (var i = 1; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
          var_name += '_';
          var_name += data[i];
      }
      socket.emit('debugVar', {
        var_value: value,
        var_name: var_name ,
        var_index: var_index 
      });
      kb = keyboard;
  }
});
```

Then ...

```
socket.on('debugReturn', function(msg) {
    if (msg == 1) {
        $('.ui-keyboard input').css('box-shadow', 'inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6)');
        kb.options.validate = true;
        kb.accept();
        kb.options.validate: function(keyboard, value, isClosing) {
          var data = $(keyboard['el']).attr('id').split('_');
          var var_index = data[data.length - 1];
          var var_name = data[0];
          for (var i = 1; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
              var_name += '_';
              var_name += data[i];
          }
          socket.emit('debugVar', {
            var_value: value,
            var_name: var_name ,
            var_index: var_index 
         });
         kb = keyboard;;
    } else {
        $('.ui-keyboard input').css('box-shadow', 'inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(255,0,0,.6)');
    }
```

});